# What is the most private option for 2FA with OpenSSH?

Tags: multi-factor, openssh

When I watch the logs on my server there are always many hundred IP addresses with failed ssh logins.

Because fail2ban only slows the attack process down, I decided that I need another solution. First with SSH key-based login, but there I had big issues with cross platform tools like putty, so I implemented 2FA on my server and it works.

The Problem is that I currently use google-authenticator and have big privacy concerns. Are there any other options that work with openssh-server? And if so which are the most private / secure ones.

Comment: Do you use a Google Authenticator app with a generic 2FA plugin for OpenSSH, or a Google Authenticator plugin for OpenSSH? If the first, you can almost certainly switch to a different 2FA app which supports the same algorithm - there are quite a few around.

Comment: What cross-platform issues are you having? puttygen can import & export keys between PEM and it's own format.

Comment: what privacy concerns?

Comment: privacy concerns because of google . And I use google auth PAM plugin for Openssh-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public key auth is definitely the best way to go here, as it is very well supported (including by PuTTY, for all that it insists on using its own key format just to make life a hassle for its users). If you really want to do something based on password auth, though, TOTP in general works fine. This is the algorithm behind Google Authenticator, but it is used all over the place and is in no way tied to Google. There are any number of "Google Authenticator"-compatible apps, for all platforms including esoteric ones, that are neither developed by Google nor require any kind of Google account or use any Google service.

With that said, since you asked about privacy in particular, note that users of SSH public key auth usually just have one public key, which they send to all the sites they log into. That key can potentially be used to find out what other sites the user is on, and potentially tie back to the user's real identity. This *can* be avoided by generating unique keypairs for each host and telling your client which key to use for each host (either at connection time on the command line / API, or automatically [using a config file](https://serverfault.com/questions/295768/how-do-i-connect-to-ssh-with-a-different-public-key)).